# Where can we check if Snowflake Database was down or restarted?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Where/How do we check if my snowflake database was down on particular day/Time?
any information_Schema object OR MEta table where its being logged?

Answer (score 0):

you can check snowflake's current operational status here:
https://status.snowflake.com/#
If you want to see where your user is logged in you can check it here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_region.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no "restarted" as Snowflake is not a singular instance. And for "down" there is only outages, which can be subscribed to.

> To subscribe, go to the [Status Page](https://status.snowflake.com/) page and click “[SUBSCRIBE TO UPDATES.](https://status.snowflake.com/)” To ensure that you only receive notifications that impact you, please subscribe to your specific region. You can find more detailed instructions on how to subscribe [here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-get-notified-of-service-alerts-automatically).

There can be "lack of service" if you incorrectly configure to WAREHOUSE's to not auto start, AND someone stops the WAREHOUSE then you will have no service. But you kind have done this to yourself. But WAREHOUSE "status" can be views via [system tables](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_metering_history.html)

*"restarted" - well technically, an warehouse can have problems and be restarted, and this can impact query completion, it can be seen in the query performance counters like [Warehouse Monitor](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-load-monitoring.html) via `Queued (Provisioning)`, &   `Queued (Repairing)` OR [QUERY_HISTORY View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) `QUEUED_PROVISIONING_TIME`, & `QUEUED_REPAIR_TIME`